# why I am getting 'NaN' for '&' operator?

Tags: javascript, binary, nan, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I am not able to understand why I am getting this "NaN" while performing AND-Bitwise operator for some numbers only? please see pic I attached to understand My issue clearly.

```js
'use strict';

function getMaxLessThanK(n, k) {


  let toknowNum = [];
  let bitVal = [];
  let topop = [];
  if (2 <= n && n <= Math.pow(10, 3) && 2 <= k && k <= n) {
    let z = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
      for (let j = 2 + z; j <= n; j++) {
        if (i !== j) {
          toknowNum.push([i, j]);

        }
      }
      z++;
    }

    toknowNum.forEach(val => {
      bitVal.push(parseInt((val[0].toString(2) & val[1].toString(2)), 2))
      console.log( val, parseInt((val[0].toString(2) & val[1].toString(2)), 2))
    })

    bitVal.sort();

    bitVal.forEach(val => {
      if (val < k) {
        topop.push(val);
      }
    })

    return topop.pop();
  }
  console.log(toknowNum, bitVal);
  return 'please check enter values';
}
console.log(getMaxLessThanK(8, 4));
```

[here is my issue pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaBVR.png)

Comment: Because, you should try to use debugger to see what’s wrong. It really helps sometimes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of `bitVal.push(parseInt((val[0].toString(2) & val[1].toString(2)), 2))` line.

In your example, let's consider val = [4,8]
Now, `val[0].toString(2)` would be `100` and `val[1].toString(2)` would be `1000`.\

So, when you perform `(val[0].toString(2) & val[1].toString(2))` it would be `"100" & "1000"`(Note that both are strings).

But, since JS cannot perform bitwise operation on strings, these strings would be converted in to interger (with base 10), so the above operation would be `100 & 1000` (Note that both are converted integers), which will result in a value `96` (Actual value after performing binary &).

And now, when you try to do `bitVal.push(parseInt((val[0].toString(2) & val[1].toString(2)), 2))`, it would be `bitVal.push(parseInt(96, 2))`. Since `96` is not a binary number, the `parseInt(96,2)` would be `NaN`.

To fix this, just update this line to as follow:
`bitVal.push(val[0] & val[1])`.

Full code as follow:

```js
'use strict';

function getMaxLessThanK(n, k) {


  let toknowNum = [];
  let bitVal = [];
  let topop = [];
  if (2 <= n && n <= Math.pow(10, 3) && 2 <= k && k <= n) {
    let z = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
      for (let j = 2 + z; j <= n; j++) {
        if (i !== j) {
          toknowNum.push([i, j]);

        }
      }
      z++;
    }

    toknowNum.forEach(val => {
      bitVal.push(val[0] & val[1])
      console.log(val, (val[0] & val[1]))
    })

    bitVal.sort();

    bitVal.forEach(val => {
      if (val < k) {
        topop.push(val);
      }
    })

    return topop.pop();
  }
  console.log(toknowNum, bitVal);
  return 'please check enter values';
}
console.log(getMaxLessThanK(8, 4));
```

Comment: I am kind full to your help.